# Looking for an alternative to \numexpr: an intuitive interface for LaTeX numeric expressions

Tags: expansion, variable, arithmetic

The `xparse` package makes writing commands easier and more flexible. The `ifthen` package does the same to conditionals. Is there a similar package for numeric expressions? Even better if it interacts well with TiKZ, that is to say inside a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: The `numerica` package allows evaluating expressions in `LaTeX` format. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648386/218142.

Comment: What do you need to do with those numerical expressions? Where do you need them in your TikZ picture?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Basically what I do in my answer below: accept integer arguments to a command, and perform some simple arithmetic and branching with them. The command's body is a `tikzpicture`. I want to avoid `\numberexpr`, `\edef`, `ifx`, etc. as much as possible. I find their usage non-intuitive and hard to understand and remember.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel More concretely, I'm rewriting Marijn's `\tikzcube` command from [an answer they gave to another post of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666559/21685) as to get rid of its dependence on the global variables `\lvcl` and `\cllv`, and to replace `\edef`, `\numexpr`, and `\ifnum` by higher-level alternatives.

Comment: PGF/TikZ brings its own mathematical engine which it uses basically everywhere: [PGFMath](https://tikz.dev/math). `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cllv-1}` Though, you could just put `\cllv-1` into the coordinate specifications because TikZ will forward it to PGFMath anyway and you don't necessary have to pre-evaluate it. Unless your cube has more than 16000 levels you will be fine with PGFMath. (Undocumented, PGF/TikZ has a clone of `\inteval`: `\pgfinteval` for a cube with 2•10⁹ levels.) For high precision, you're going to need the `fpu` library but that is not needed to draw stuff

Comment: PGFMath also has an `ifthenelse` function but it doesn't provide an interface to do to something depending on the evaluation. For usage of styles I always use `/utils/if` key [(Code 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652565) or just something like the `.try` handler as in my answer to your linked Q.

Comment: I thought \numexpr was intuitive.  Try doing it using \advance, \multiply and \divide.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Too bad TikZ doesn't have an `\if` to complement its `\foreach`. Is it possible to assign the result of a calculation to a variable in TikZ, e.g. `\x = 1 + 2\y`, similar to `etoolbox`'s `\numdef`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\numexpr` also sometimes requires `\relax` right? I don't want to deal with these low-level commands.

Comment: `\relax` just tells the parser to stop adding stuff.  You can generally use `{\numexpr ...}` instead (although `{}` is also a low level command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fpeval` for numeric expressions

[image]

showing cos 30 degrees is (sqrt 3)/2

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{10/3}


\fpeval{cosd 30}


\fpeval{4*(cosd 30)^2}


\end{document}
```

Similarly you can use `\inteval` for integer  expressions

Comment: Thank you. What about integer arithmetic?

Comment: @EvanAad `\inteval{1+2}` although that is more or less `\the\numexpr`

Comment: You forget a package?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro no. If you have an old latex you may need `xfp` package to define `\fpeval` but it has been defined in the format for a while  now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Using `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\isSuccessor}[2]% successor, number
{%
   \numdef{\prev}{#1-1}%
   #1 is
   \ifnumequal{\prev}{#2}{indeed}{not}
   the successor of #2.%
}
\begin{document}
\isSuccessor{42}{41}\par
\isSuccessor{43}{41}\par
\isSuccessor{41}{42}
\end{document}
```

[image: Results of arithmetic operations and tests with etoolbox]

---

Using `pgfmath` for the mathematical calculations, `\edef` for the variable assignment, and `ifthen` for the conditionals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand{\isSuccessor}[2]
{
   \pgfmathparse{int(#1-1)}%
   \edef\prev{\pgfmathresult}%
   #1 is
   \ifthenelse{\prev=#2}{indeed}{not}
   the successor of #2.%
}
\begin{document}
\isSuccessor{42}{41}\par
\isSuccessor{43}{41}\par
\isSuccessor{41}{42}
\end{document}
```

The output is the save as above.